# Failed insert into sql db,exception:java com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Must declare the scalar variable "@P7@P8"

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hello when i try click a button my expectation is to insert the whole data from the array list into table in sql,but i have this error:
java com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Must declare the scalar variable "@P7@P8".

```
    private static final String DB = "InPrepaid";
   private static final String HOST = "wilson";
```

My connect method:

```
          private static void connect1() {
      try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://" + HOST + 
       ";database=" + DB + ";integratedSecurity=true");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

My method for inserting data:

```
private static void insertSfi(List<SIMs_for_Import> sfiList) throws 
 SQLException {
     PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    connect1();
    if (!sfiList.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sfiList.size(); i++) {
            //  connect();
            //  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String insertSimsImportSQL = "INSERT INTO SIMs_for_Import (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6,FIELD7,FIELD8,FIELD9,FIELD10,FIELD11,FIELD12,FIELD13,IMSI,SIMNO,FIELD16,FIELD17,FIELD18,FIELD19,FIELD20,FIELD21,FIELD22,FIELD23,FIELD24,FIELD99,AUTH_VER) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pstmt=conn1.prepareStatement(insertSimsImportSQL);

            pstmt.setString(1, sfiList.get(i).getField1());
            pstmt.setString(2, sfiList.get(i).getField2());
            pstmt.setString(3, sfiList.get(i).getField3());
            pstmt.setString(4, sfiList.get(i).getField4());
            pstmt.setString(5, sfiList.get(i).getField5());
            pstmt.setString(6, sfiList.get(i).getField6());
            pstmt.setString(7, sfiList.get(i).getField7());
            pstmt.setString(8, sfiList.get(i).getField8());
            pstmt.setString(9, sfiList.get(i).getField9());
            pstmt.setString(10, sfiList.get(i).getField10());
            pstmt.setString(11, sfiList.get(i).getField11());
            pstmt.setString(12, sfiList.get(i).getField12());
            pstmt.setString(13, sfiList.get(i).getField13());
            pstmt.setString(14, sfiList.get(i).getImsi());
            pstmt.setString(15, sfiList.get(i).getSimno());
            pstmt.setString(16, sfiList.get(i).getField16());
            pstmt.setString(17, sfiList.get(i).getField17());
            pstmt.setString(18, sfiList.get(i).getField18());
            pstmt.setString(19, sfiList.get(i).getField19());
            pstmt.setString(20, sfiList.get(i).getField20());
            pstmt.setString(21, sfiList.get(i).getField21());
            pstmt.setString(22, sfiList.get(i).getField22());
            pstmt.setString(23, sfiList.get(i).getField23());
            pstmt.setString(24, sfiList.get(i).getField124());
            pstmt.setString(25, sfiList.get(i).getField99());
            pstmt.setString(26, sfiList.get(i).getAuth_ver());
             pstmt.executeQuery();
             pstmt.close();
        }

    } else {

    }

}
```

When i click the button in the app i invoke it with this:

```
                            connect1();

                            insertSfi(sfiList)
```

My class:

```
   public class SIMs_for_Import {

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;
private String field4;
private String field5;
private String field6;
private String field7;
private String field8;
private String field9;
private String field10;
private String field11;
private String field12;
private String field13;
private String imsi;
private String simno;
private String field16;
private String field17;
private String field18;
private String field19;
private String field20;
private String field21;
private String field22;
private String field23;
private String field124;
private String field99;
private String auth_ver;

public SIMs_for_Import(){

}

public SIMs_for_Import(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4, String field5, String field6, String field7, String field8, String field9, String field10, String field11, String field12, String field13, String imsi, String simno, String field16, String field17, String field18, String field19, String field20, String field21, String field22, String field23, String field124, String field99, String auth_ver) {
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
    this.field4 = field4;
    this.field5 = field5;
    this.field6 = field6;
    this.field7 = field7;
    this.field8 = field8;
    this.field9 = field9;
    this.field10 = field10;
    this.field11 = field11;
    this.field12 = field12;
    this.field13 = field13;
    this.imsi = imsi;
    this.simno = simno;
    this.field16 = field16;
    this.field17 = field17;
    this.field18 = field18;
    this.field19 = field19;
    this.field20 = field20;
    this.field21 = field21;
    this.field22 = field22;
    this.field23 = field23;
    this.field124 = field124;
    this.field99 = field99;
    this.auth_ver = auth_ver;
}

public String getField1() {
    return field1;
}

public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public String getField2() {
    return field2;
}

public void setField2(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}

public String getField3() {
    return field3;
}

public void setField3(String field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}

public String getField4() {
    return field4;
}

public void setField4(String field4) {
    this.field4 = field4;
}

public String getField5() {
    return field5;
}

public void setField5(String field5) {
    this.field5 = field5;
}

public String getField6() {
    return field6;
}

public void setField6(String field6) {
    this.field6 = field6;
}

public String getField7() {
    return field7;
}

public void setField7(String field7) {
    this.field7 = field7;
}

public String getField8() {
    return field8;
}

public void setField8(String field8) {
    this.field8 = field8;
}

public String getField9() {
    return field9;
}

public void setField9(String field9) {
    this.field9 = field9;
}

public String getField10() {
    return field10;
}

public void setField10(String field10) {
    this.field10 = field10;
}

public String getField11() {
    return field11;
}

public void setField11(String field11) {
    this.field11 = field11;
}

public String getField12() {
    return field12;
}

public void setField12(String field12) {
    this.field12 = field12;
}

public String getField13() {
    return field13;
}

public void setField13(String field13) {
    this.field13 = field13;
}

public String getImsi() {
    return imsi;
}

public void setImsi(String imsi) {
    this.imsi = imsi;
}

public String getSimno() {
    return simno;
}

public void setSimno(String simno) {
    this.simno = simno;
}

public String getField16() {
    return field16;
}

public void setField16(String field16) {
    this.field16 = field16;
}

public String getField17() {
    return field17;
}

public void setField17(String field17) {
    this.field17 = field17;
}

public String getField18() {
    return field18;
}

public void setField18(String field18) {
    this.field18 = field18;
}

public String getField19() {
    return field19;
}

public void setField19(String field19) {
    this.field19 = field19;
}

public String getField20() {
    return field20;
}

public void setField20(String field20) {
    this.field20 = field20;
}

public String getField21() {
    return field21;
}

public void setField21(String field21) {
    this.field21 = field21;
}

public String getField22() {
    return field22;
}

public void setField22(String field22) {
    this.field22 = field22;
}

public String getField23() {
    return field23;
}

public void setField23(String field23) {
    this.field23 = field23;
}

public String getField124() {
    return field124;
}

public void setField124(String field124) {
    this.field124 = field124;
}

public String getField99() {
    return field99;
}

public void setField99(String field99) {
    this.field99 = field99;
}

public String getAuth_ver() {
    return auth_ver;
}

public void setAuth_ver(String auth_ver) {
    this.auth_ver = auth_ver;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has to do with your double question marks here without commas between them. Notice your 7th and 8th question mark don't have a comma between them

```
 String insertSimsImportSQL = "INSERT INTO SIMs_for_Import (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,FIELD6,FIELD7,FIELD8,FIELD9,FIELD10,FIELD11,FIELD12,FIELD13,IMSI,SIMNO,FIELD16,FIELD17,FIELD18,FIELD19,FIELD20,FIELD21,FIELD22,FIELD23,FIELD24,FIELD99,AUTH_VER) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,??,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: You were right but now i have an exception: String or binary data would be truncated.  is this mean that i try to insert data which is bigger in tha db?

Comment: yes, the data you are trying to insert is too big for that certain column

Comment: im sorry but for the last:is there a chance to understand where?

Comment: You would need to post the table definition as well as the data you are trying to insert.  Also post the exact exception message.

Comment: This is my data the ; is the separator for the columns' 28401;MBD010951;01;990850;;;29062018;M-TEL GSM BG;;GRP;001;;420008;284010160729313;8935901990857293139;056E55C794A8AEF4E03777B642E2F8EC;0000;6847;85232822;87439730;0008;;;67432053;;;'

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: They all look fine.  I hope you checked yourself too.  But I would now check that the correct fields are being set in your SIMs_for_Import class.  Perhaps some debug logging would help.